# MVC url routing with slug and id. Makes a mess with default routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, slug

Im trying to get my urls to look nice and seo friendly with slugs. I tought I suceeded but then my default routing stopped working.
When I go to this example.com/location/viewlocation/528 then the url ends up like example.com/528/a-nice-location

So thats good!
But now my normal stuff dosent work.
Typing in example.com/home/index results in the error

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult ViewLocation(Int32, System.String)' in 'Oplev.Controllers.LocationController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

I have tried different solutions but I a missing something. Cant get it to work.

My code:
**RouteConfig**

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "view_location",
            url: "{id}/{slug}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Location", action = "ViewLocation", id = UrlParameter.Optional, slug = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

**Location controller**

```
public ActionResult ViewLocation(int id, string slug)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(slug))
        {
            slug = "a-nice-location"; // testing..
            return RedirectToRoute("view_location", new { id = id, slug = slug });
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**Home controller**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first route matches anything with 0, 1 or 2 segments in the url. For example it matches `../Home/Index`. You need some way to distinguish it, for example you could make it

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "view_location",
    url: "ViewLocation/{id}/{slug}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Location", action = "ViewLocation", slug = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

or you could add a route constraint

Note also that only the last parameter can be marked as `UrlParameter.Optional`, but in your case the `id` is not optional anyway

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I somehow ended up with something that works!
Changed routing for view_location to this:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "view_location",
            url: "{id}/{slug}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Location", action = "ViewLocation", slug = UrlParameter.Optional},
            constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
        );
```

Comment: Or you can use `int?` type instead of `int`. The message is straightforward: if you're using non-nullable type you need to declare numeric constraint for the route.

Answer (score 0):

This is meant to supplement the already given answers. Attribute routing with route constraints will also work.

First make sure attribute routing is enabled in `RouteConfig`

```
//Attribute routing
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); // placed before convention-based routes

//convention-based routes
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Next use the necessary `Route` attributes on the controller

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{id:int}/{*slug?}", Name = "view_location")] // Matches GET 528/some-nice-location
public ActionResult ViewLocation(int id, string slug) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(slug)) {
        slug = "a-nice-location"; // testing..
        return RedirectToRoute("view_location", new { id = id, slug = slug });
    }
    return View();
}
```